# Is there a way to force "low power" graphics?

Tags: macos, battery, graphics, preferences, power-management

Is there a plist or hidden config to set my graphics/energy preference to "Always use low power/ integrated graphics"?

Seems like energy saver preferences only allow choosing between:

1. Smart auto graphics switching
2. Always use high-powered graphics

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> gfxCardStatus is an unobtrusive menu bar app for OS X that allows
>   MacBook Pro users to see which apps are affecting their battery life
>   by using the more power-hungry graphics.

https://gfx.io

By this way you can simply disable your graphic card by an icon in your menu bar.

Comment: It's always nice to be introduced to new/useful plugins :). Upvoted.

Comment: @SaphrynShikaze totally agree :)